# What is the thought process to solving anagrams à la Countdown

Tags: british-english

I'm not sure if this best belongs on this Stack Exchange site, or some psychological one, but here goes. I'm wondering what the thought process behind solving anagrams is, as in, pulling words out of random letters, like in the game [Countdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_%28game_show%29).

I am never very good at this game, and I think it's because I'm not going about it in the right way.

I look at a letter, "D" for example, then think of words I know that begin with D, and go through them ruling each out as a letter in the word isn't in my group of letters. It's obviously a very poor way of doing it.

How do you find words in a collection of letters?

Comment: I would try http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/ (Cognitive Science)

Comment: I think this link may be of interest to you: http://tees.openrepository.com/tees/bitstream/10149/129839/2/129839.pdf

Answer (score 2):

One way is to search first for the letters that make up common word endings – -ing, -ed, -er, etc. – and once one (or more) has been found, look to the remaining letters for a verb or noun onto which the ending might be placed. If there's an "s" remaining, stick it on the end!

As a crossword solver for several decades, this is certainly my approach to anagrams. For stubborn ones, a three by three grid (for nine letter words) with the letters arranged within (vowels in the middle line) seems to help.